# Inserting data into MySQL not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm learning php and I'm having trouble inserting into a MySQL database (for testing purposes). I run the code below and I'm not faced with an error, however the records are not visible in my tables; It's like I anything never happened in the db. Please help, code below:

```
<?php

//Variable - Declaring the connection
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','joe','12345678') 
or die(mysql_error());

//selecting the database
mysql_select_db('users',$con);

//Variable - Declare SQL statement to insert
$sql="INSERT INTO users (name,lastname) VALUES('carl','')";

mysql_query($sql,$con);

?>
```

The database details are:

```
server : localhost
user : joe (full permissions)
password : 12345678
database name : test
table name : users
field names : name and lastname\
```

Help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Joseph

Comment: Just some clarification: PHPMyAdmin is the **front-end** for the **MySQL database** you have.

Comment: You're not looking for any errors, so it's not surprising that you don't see any. Start by checking the return value of `mysql_query()`, and if it's `false` look at `mysql_error` for the error message.

Comment: Do a SELECT * FROM users;

Comment: Read the manual and take note of the huge red box: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-select-db.php

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting db user but have DB test...

Comment: Hey thanks for the instant reply. I've changed that since it was a silly mistake and it worked.

Comment: @user2612009: You should accept this (or any other) answer if it answers your question (when you are able to do so, of course).

Answer (score 4):

I think this might happen to be your immediate issue:

```
mysql_select_db('users',$con);
```

You select the DB named **users**, whereas you stated the DB name to be **test**. Try this instead

```
mysql_select_db('test',$con);
```

However, based on your question, I think it would be very useful to read up on the basic components you are dealing with: the [DBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database), the objects used in MySQL (database, table, user, etc...), the front end...

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it this line;

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (name,lastname) VALUES('carl','')";
```

Should be changed to this;

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (`name`, `lastname`) VALUES('carl','')";
```

To clarify the " ` " were missing from the field names of the table.

Hope this helps.